# Trying to implement a filter feature on my mapping of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im struggling to implement a search filter on my mapping of crypto data. I am not sure what to put inside the render. Do I even need to include a render? as I am using data called in from my static.config.js file which already renders the data. I will add the static.config.js file too as I think this will aid the question.

Thank You

`render() {
return(
 )
}`

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouteData, Link } from 'react-static'

class Currencies extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    };
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0,20)});
  }
}
render() {
  return(

  )
}

export default withRouteData(({ currencies }) => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/">Quoinex</Link>
    <Link to="/qryptos"><b>Qryptos</b></Link>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} value={this.state.search} placeholder="BTC etc."  />
      <input className="sub" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <h1>Tokens</h1>
    <br />
    <table className="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Crypto/Token</th>
        <th>Min Withdrawal Qty</th>
        <th>Min Order Qty</th>
      </tr>
      { currencies.filter((currency) => {return currency.name.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;} ).map(currency => (
        <tr key={currency.currency}>
          <td id="tokenName">{currency.currency}</td>
          <td>{currency.minimum_withdrawal}</td>
          <td>{currency.minimum_order_quantity}</td> 
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  </div>
))
```

Static.config.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default {
  getSiteData: () => ({
    title: 'React Static',
  }),
  getRoutes: async () => {
    const { data: productsquoinex } = await axios.get('https://api.quoine.com/currencies')
    const {data: currencies } = await axios.get('https://api.qryptos.com/currencies')
    return [

      {
        path: '/',
        component: 'src/containers/Marketsquoinex',
        getData: () => ({
          productsquoinex,
        }),
        children: productsquoinex.map(product => ({
          path: `/product/${product.id}`,
          getData: () => ({
            product,
          }),
        })),
      },
      {
        path: '/qryptos',
        component: 'src/containers/Currencies',
        getData: () => ({
          currencies,
        }),
        children: currencies.map(currency => ({
          path: `/currencies/${currency}`,
          getData: () => ({
            currency,
          }),
        })),
      },
      {
        is404: true,
        component: 'src/containers/404',
      },
    ]
  },
  renderToHtml: (render, Comp, meta) => {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const html = render(sheet.collectStyles(<Comp />))
    meta.styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement()
    return html
  },
  Document: class CustomHtml extends Component {

    render () {

      const {
        Html, Head, Body, children, renderMeta
      } = this.props


      return (
        <Html>
          <Head>
            <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            {renderMeta.styleTags}
          </Head>
          <Body>
            {children}
          </Body>
        </Html>
      )
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Can't you just render the component that holds the data? Normally it's better if the parent fetches the data if it's from an API and send it down to it's children which normally should be purely presentational.

Comment: the component you are exporting doesn't have state. I think you're very confused about how react works based on this code sample. maybe try following along with the main react docs before jumping into react-static code?